# Eclipse plugin tutorials

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to develop an eclipse plugin to show some special functions with Eclipse Java Editor. Except for these minor changes all other things should be same as a normal Eclipse Java Editor. What are some Eclipse plugin development tutorials to help me get started?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-plugindev1/) is a nice tutorial for Eclipse plug-in development.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you may want to look at for helpful info on extending the JDT:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecjdt/
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_extend_the_JDT%3F

The following are a bit more general on creating editors:

- http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-ecl-commplgin1.html (and parts 2 and 3)